# How to combine multiple rxjs BehaviourSubjects

Tags: rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm building out an Angular2 app, and have two `BehaviourSubjects` that I want to logically combine into one subscription.  I'm making two http requests and want to fire an event when both of them come back.  I'm looking at `forkJoin` vs `combineLatest`.  It seems that combineLatest will fire when either behvaviorSubjects are updated vs forkJoin will fire only after all behavoirSubjects are updated.  Is this correct?  There has to be a generally accepted pattern for this isn't there?

**EDIT**
Here is an example of one of my behaviorSubjects my angular2 component is subscribing to:

```js
export class CpmService {

    public cpmSubject: BehaviorSubject<Cpm[]>;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.cpmSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Cpm[]>(new Array<Cpm>());
    }

    getCpm(id: number): void {
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('Id', id.toString());

        this._http.get('a/Url/Here', { search: params })
            .map(response => <Cpm>response.json())
            .subscribe(_cpm => {
                this.cpmSubject.subscribe(cpmList => {
                    //double check we dont already have the cpm in the observable, if we dont have it, push it and call next to propigate new cpmlist everywheres
                    if (! (cpmList.filter((cpm: Cpm) => cpm.id === _cpm.id).length > 0) ) {
                        cpmList.push(_cpm);
                        this.cpmSubject.next(cpmList);
                    }
                })
            });
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of my component's subscription:

```
  this._cpmService.cpmSubject.subscribe(cpmList => {
      doSomeWork();
  });
```

But instead of firing doSomeWork() on the single subscription I want to only fire doSomeWork() when the cpmSubject and fooSubject fire.

Comment: A http-request cannot directly return a `BehaviorSubject` - I'm assuming, that you are `nexting` the http-responses each into a `BehaviorSubject` or are maybe even subscribing the `Subject` to the `get/post/put`?

Comment: @olsn yes, I'm subscribing to http responses and nexting my subjects with their response in service classes

Comment: The public access to an behaviour subject is an anti pattern. Please use a getter with an downcast with "as Observable" instead. So you can't use the next call outside the service -> separation of concerns

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the `zip`-operator, which works similar to combineLatest or forkJoin, but triggers only when both streams have emitted: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

The difference between `zip` and `combineLatest` is:
Zip will only trigger *"in parallel"*, whereas `combineLatest` will trigger with any update and emit the latest value of each stream.
So, assuming the following 2 streams:

```
streamA => 1--2--3
streamB => 10-20-30
```

with `zip`:

- "1, 10"
- "2, 20"
- "3, 30"

with `combineLatest`:

- "1, 10"
- "2, 10"
- "2, 20"
- "3, 20"
- "3, 30"

Here is also a live-example:

```js
const a = new Rx.Subject();
const b = new Rx.Subject();

Rx.Observable.zip(a,b)
  .subscribe(x => console.log("zip: " + x.join(", ")));
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a,b)
  .subscribe(x => console.log("combineLatest: " + x.join(", ")));

a.next(1);
b.next(10);
a.next(2);
b.next(20);
a.next(3);
b.next(30);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

Also another sidenote: Never ever ever subscribe inside a subscribe.
Do something like this instead:

```
this._http.get('a/Url/Here', { search: params })
            .map(response => <Cpm>response.json())
            .withLatestFrom(this.cpmSubject)
            .subscribe([_cpm, cpmList] => {
                if (! (cpmList.filter((cpm: Cpm) => cpm.id === _cpm.id).length > 0) ) {
                    cpmList.push(_cpm);
                    this.cpmSubject.next(cpmList);
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the difference between zip and combineLatest?

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer.  I'm trying to try it out but I'm not finding a zip method on my Rx.Observable object.

Comment: in case you have not imported the whole library, make sure to add it via `import "rxjs/add/observable/zip"`; - it does exist: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e91d113e49acc9b0e12e2524040fa84cf3fa2c78/src/observable/zip.ts